# How to set driver java options in SparkLauncher

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-launcher

When using `spark-submit` to submit a Spark app to Yarn, I can pass java options to the driver via the `--driver-java-options`, for example:

```
spark-submit --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///conf/log4j.properties" ...
```

How do I achieve the same when submitting via [`SparkLauncher`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/launcher/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.java)? In particular, is there a way to achieve it with Spark 1.4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not familiar with `SparkLauncher` but from looking at the code it appears you can pass configuration with `setConf()`. In this if you add the property `SparkLauncher.DRIVER_EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS` this should have the same effect.

For example

```
Process spark = new SparkLauncher()
     .setAppResource("/my/app.jar")
     .setMainClass("my.spark.app.Main")
     .setMaster("local[*]")
     .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS, "-Dmy.property=someval")
     .launch();
```

Comment: Are you sure ? From https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html
"Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the --driver-java-options command line option or in your default properties file. "

Comment: I don't think the question is referring to client mode, tbh functionality of SparkLauncher has probably changed between version 1.4 and 2.1 (the version linked in your comment)